# Load URL in Default Browser and Bring to Front

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a fullscreen application written in c++ using straight winapi.  The application contains an embedded web browser (using CEF, but I don't think that matters in this case).  I am currently intercepting any popup windows as the result of clicking on a link and opening them in the systems default browser using ShellExecute.  However, on many of our test systems the browser window is displayed behind my application window, which is a problem since my window covers up the task bar so the user has no indication that a new window has been displayed.

I've read everything I can find on this site and others and have not been able to find a single solution that works:

1. Using ShellExecuteEx to get the process handle, then using the process handle to find the window handle and bringing it to the front - Many times the process handle is NULL, which appears to be related to the browser opening a new tab in an existing window.  In addition, if Edge is the default browser then the process handle always seems to be NULL.
2. Using ShellExecute (or Ex) then finding the new window based on the name - I have no idea what the name of the window will be.  It's based on the content that is opened, which may be many different things depending on the link the user clicked (html, pdf, etc).
3. Attempting to figure out the path to the default browser and then launching it using CreateProcess - So far I haven't had any luck with this if Edge is the default (since apparently Edge is a "modern" application that doesn't have an executable that can be launched with CreateProcess). If anyone knows how to make this work I could see this actually being a decent solution.

So right now I'm heading down a path of enumerating all of the windows before and after launching the browser and attempting to figure out which one is the correct one to bring forward.  I'm envisioning all sorts of issues that could possibly occur (a tab opening on an existing browser for instance).  If anyone has any solution to the issue I would appreciate it!

Edit: Code I'm using for ShellExecuteEx:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO sxi = { 0 };
sxi.cbSize = sizeof( sxi );
sxi.nShow = SW_NORMAL;
sxi.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS | SEE_MASK_NOASYNC | SEE_MASK_WAITFORINPUTIDLE;
sxi.lpVerb = _T( "open" );
sxi.lpFile = url;
if( ShellExecuteEx( &sxi ) )
```

Comment: "*the browser window is displayed behind my application window*" - when calling `ShellExecute/Ex()`, are you passing your application's `HWND` as the owner window for the spawned process? If not, you should be.

Comment: Please show the code that calls `ShellExecuteEx()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wasn't passing in a window handle.  Just tested with the handle to my main application window, but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: @zett42 Code: See updated question for code.

Comment: Normally the system does the right thing, when you pass a window handle to `ShellExecuteEx`. It might behave differently in case the window is a fullscreen window. For one, it automatically hides the taskbar, so it wouldn't supprise me if other things behave differently too. Try to toggle fullscreen mode before you call `ShellExecuteEx` to rule out such behaviours.

Comment: @zett42 Just tried it when not in fullscreen, same behavior.  I believe Windows is deciding that the browser window isn't allowed to be in front of my application window since the browser wasn't opened with a user action (as far as it knows).  The Edge icon also flashes orange on the taskbar when this occurs.  Unfortunately, without the process id for the browser I can't make use of AllowSetForgroundWindow.

Comment: I have never experienced a similar problem with `ShellExecuteEx`, when passing the handle of my applications main window. You can try `AllowSetForgroundWindow(ASFW_ANY)`.

Comment: @zett42 `AllowSetForgroundWindow(ASFW_ANY)` solved the problem.  Please submit it as an answer!